# potential memory leak using TriMap in Scala and Tomcat

Tags: scala, tomcat, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I am using a `scala.collection.concurrent.TriMap` wrapped in an object to store configuration values that are fetched remotely.

```scala
object persistentMemoryMap {
  val storage: TrieMap[String, CacheEntry] = TrieMap[String, CacheEntry]()
}
```

It works just fine but I have noticed that when Tomcat is shut down it logs some alarming messages about potential memory leaks

```
2013-jun-27 08:58:22 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
ALLVARLIG: The web application [] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom$1@5d529976]) and a value of type [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom] (value [scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom@59d941d7]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak
```

I am guessing this thread will terminate on it's own eventually but I am wondering if there is some way to kill it or should I just leave it alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ThreadLocalRandom`'s value is created only once per thread. It does not hold any references to objects other than the random value generator used by that thread -- the memory it consumes has a fixed size. Once the thread is garbage collected, its thread local random value will be collected as well -- you should just let the GC do its work.

You could still remove it manually by using Java reflection to remove the `private` modifier on the static field `localRandom` in the `ThreadLocalRandom` class:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/forkjoin/scala/concurrent/forkjoin/ThreadLocalRandom.java#L62

You could then call `localRandom.set(null)` to null out the reference to the random number generator. You should also then ensure that `TrieMap` is no longer used from that thread, otherwise `ThreadLocalRandom` will break by assuming that the random number generator is different than `null`.

Seems hacky to me, and I think you should just stick to letting the GC collect the thread local value.